# Node console.log truncates output by default. How can I see the full output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

Node's console.log seems to truncate output by default, eg, looking at the output from an API:

```
{ '@': { xmlns: 'http://ec2.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-03-01/' },
   requestId: '123456',
   reservationSet: 
   { item: 
      { reservationId: 'r-123456',
       ownerId: '123456',
       groupSet: [Object],
       instancesSet: [Object],
       requesterId: '123456' } } }
```

As you can see, `[object]` isn't expanded. I guess this is a convenience measure - a lot of people wouldn't want node spewing thousands of lines by default. Is there a way I can tell it to expand the logged item's contents?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There is no option to change `console.log`, however you can use a function in the bundled util library, [`util.inspect`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.9/api/util.html#util.inspect) which does accept a depth parameter. Eg:

```
 console.log(require('util').inspect(obj, true, 10)); // 10 levels deep
```